# How to "CTRL + Click" in cypress, pages are linked but ctrl + click does not take me to the correct page

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, cypress

I have two files, a spec file and a page object file.
I have imported the page object file inside the spec file.
My issue is that when i try to CTRL + click on a reference inside the spec file, it does not take me to the page object file.

The test runs ok but i would like this functionality to be active. What am i missing?

Spec file:

```
const constants = require("../support/constants")
const positionPage = require("../support/page_objects/positionPage")


describe('Create New Position', () => {

    it('Log In', () => {
        cy.visit(Cypress.env('staging'))
        cy.logIn(Cypress.env('username'), Cypress.env('password'))
    })

    it('Expand menu', () => {
        positionPage.expandMenuButton.click()
    })

    it('Open Position menu', () =>{
        positionPage.createNewPosition('Manager')
    })

})
```

Page object file:

```
/// <reference types = "cypress" />

class PositionPage {

    get expandMenuButton () {
        return cy.get('.dash-menu-header > .mobile-menu-button')
    }

    createNewPosition (positionName) {
        cy.get('#topSearchAdd > .dropdown-toggle-mousedown').click();
        cy.get('[ng-if="currentUser.userPermissions.addPosition"] > a').click()
        cy.get('.noBottomMargin > .inputTipWrap > div > .ng-pristine').type(positionName)
    }

}

export default new PositionPage()
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

The `require()` syntax seems to be stopping it.

Switching to import

```js
import positionPage from "../support/page_objects/positionPage"
```

ctrl-click here in the spec

```js
positionPage.expandMenuButton.click()
```

takes you to here in positionPage

```js
export default new PositionPage()
```

Comment: Thank you, but that will require a TS file extension.

Comment: You are mistaken, it works just as well with JS extension.